# Parcelable array not passing between activities

Tags: android

So, I'm having an issue with passing a Parcelable array between two activities. For some reason, the app blows up before it even loads the activity I'm calling.

Here is the object I am trying to pass.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Inventory implements Parcelable{
public String inventory_id = "" ;
public String vin = "" ;
public String stock = "" ;
public String new_used = "" ;
public String certified = "" ;
public String mileage = "" ;

public Inventory() {}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(inventory_id);
    dest.writeString(vin);
    dest.writeString(stock);
    dest.writeString(new_used);
    dest.writeString(certified);
    dest.writeString(mileage);
}

public Inventory(Parcel source){
    inventory_id = source.readString();
    vin = source.readString();
    stock = source.readString();
    new_used = source.readString();
    certified = source.readString();
    mileage = source.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Inventory> CREATOR = new  Parcelable.Creator<Inventory>() {

    public Inventory createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Inventory(source);
    }

    public Inventory[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Inventory[size];
    }
};    
}
```

And here is the line where I pass it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("invList", invList); //This is a list of inventory objects.
startActivity(intent);
```

This code never loads Activity2. I can create a debug point in the onCreate method in Activity 2 and it is never called. If I comment out *intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("invList", invList);*, Activity2 will load, but of course blows up when I get to the line that needs the invList, which leads me to believe that something is happening with the Parcelable objects between activities. I get nothing in my LogCat. It just reloads Activity1.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the stack trace, that is very helpful.

Comment: How many inventory items (objects) are there?  There is a limit to the size of what you pass via extras.

Comment: @bobnoble OK. Now that's an interesting question. Something I should have mentioned in my original question. The size of the list varies. When I send in 20 objects, I have no issue. But, when it's 40, it doesn't work. What is the limit? And how do I pass large arrays through activities?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not formally define maximum size.  50K bytes seems to be about the max. Alternative to passing large data via extras is to save the data to a file, passing the URL to the file via the intent.